# Passing the string value instead of const string literal to macro with stringizing operator

Tags: c++, string, macros, string-literals

I want to pass string value into some macro called `TEST_FAIL`. I tried following code

```
string error = "myError";
TEST_FAIL(error.c_str());
TEST_FAIL("myError");
```

but the output of this is

```
error.c_str()
"myError"
```

How can I get in the first line value of string `error`, i.e `"myError"` in both lines?

I use macro from the library which is define like this

```
#define TEST_FAIL(msg) \
{                                                               \
    assertment(::Test::Source(__FILE__, __LINE__, (msg) != 0 ? #msg : "")); \
    if (!continue_after_failure()) return;                      \
}
```

Comment: The c-preprocessor runs **before** compilation, and is certainly not able to replace any values obtained at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the macro, the # before `#msg` is a macro extension that 'stringify' the expression (i.e., convert the exact expression into string. See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) for more information).

If you want to have the value of `msg`, just remove the # as following:

```
#define TEST_FAIL(msg) \
{                                                               \
    assertment(::Test::Source(__FILE__, __LINE__, (msg) != 0 ? msg : "")); \
    if (!continue_after_failure()) return;                      \
}
```

Comment: I would like to do it without changing `TEST_FAIL` macro, since this is defined in external library. Is this possible?

Comment: Macro manipulation is done before compilation. Thus, at this moment, the compiler does not know the actual value of error (which is "myError"). I'm afraid you can't do this without changing TEST_FAIL. However, you still can define your own macro with the fixed code. Macro is like "copy-paste" on steroids for your source code. But it's still on source code, not at execution time.

Comment: So, the additional macro or function will not help! Probably, the only option is to generate class with current string value and compile it at runtime. And do this again for every macro call.

Answer (score 0):

The # operator in macros converts the input parameters to a string, so passing error.c_str() will print exactly that, "error.c_str()". See here for details.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e3a913x.aspx

Comment: I already saw this before posting, but I still do not know how to pass string value to this macro.